# round time down if full hour, or up if it exeeds a full hour in php?

Tags: php, date, datetime

I'm trying to calculate the duration of services in order to get the end time. Each service has a duration value in minutes, and those are: `30`, `40`, `50`.

Every session starts at a full hour (e.g. 11:00, 12:00, 13:00).

If the total duration lands on a full hour (e.g. 12:00, 13:00, 14:00), it should be set to the hour before, and 59 minutes (e.g. 11:59, 12:59, 13:59). This happens if two 30 minutes services is selected - for example.

But if it passes an hour, say that the end time is 12:20 or 13:30, then the end time should be set to 12:59 or 13:59.

Here's my code so far:

```
$startTime = $_POST['datetime'];  //  (2015-09-09 11:00)

#   calculate total duration of services in order to get end time
    foreach($_POST['service'] as $service){
        list($service_id,$service_duration) = explode(';',$service);  //  values stored as id;duration
        $service_ids[] = (int)$service_id;  //  new array with ids
        $services_duration_total += (int)$service_duration;  //  in minutes
    }
//
#   calculate end time
    $endTime_actual = getdate(strtotime('+'.$services_duration_total.' minutes', strtotime($_POST['datetime'])));  //  actual end time
```

I tried this method:

```
$endTime_offset = (60-$endTime_actual['minutes'])-1;  //  calculate munutes left in the hour
$endTime = date('Y-m-d H:i',strtotime('+'.$endTime_offset.' minutes',$endTime_actual[0]));  //  new end time
```

This works if the total duration exceeds 60 minutes, but not if it is exactly 60 minutes, or 120 or 180 for that matter, because it then lands on a full hour. In those cases, as I mentioned, I need the script to round down to last hour, and 59 minutes..

I'm not sure if I explained this correctly, but hopefully you get what I'm trying to accomplish..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could substract 1 second and then replace the "minutes" part of the timestamp with a fixed "59":

```
$endTime = date('Y-m-d H:59', strtotime(
    sprintf('+%d minutes - 1 second', $services_duration_total),
    strtotime($_POST['datetime'])
));
```

This way, all end times from 12:01 to 13:00 are converted to 12:59 (this is how I understood your question)

Comment: This seems to be working. I had to add an `strtotime` surrounding the two last parameters in the `date` function, but after so, I run a couple of various test. looks good. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Oh, I accidently deleted strtotime from the code, fixed that now.

Comment: btw. why `-1 second`? Since I'm working with minutes, would it have any effect using `-1 minute`? Just asking out of curiosity..

Comment: I just did that to comply with "round down full hour", so 12:00:01 would not convert to 11:59. Since you only work with full minutes, you can also use -1 minute (or `$services_duration_total - 1`).

Comment: Ah. I see. Thanks for taking the tame to explain.

Answer (score 2):

Try to work with your datetime directly ( or convert it in datetime) :

you can force your datetime based on its minute value

```
$date = new DateTime('2001-01-01');

$date->setTime( $date->format('H'), 59);
```

you can also force the hour before with this : 
http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.sub.php

Hope this will help